# How easy is it to 'upgrade' from Stripe to Stripe Connect?

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment, stripe-connect, stripe.js

I am the co-founder of an online business and having a little trouble with development. My development team have already implemented Stripe on the platform, so we are currently able to sell products, accept payments, etc.

However, I want to 'upgrade' the system to use Stripe Connect, so payments are split i.e. I want some money to go to the user's account who uploaded the product and some money to go to my business account.

How easy would it be to go from our current Stripe API to implementing Stripe Connect to allow us to split payments? How long do you think it would take to implement? You can see an overview of Stripe Connect here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect

Thank you in advance for your help,

G

Comment: It all depends on the complexity of your setup and whether your are using express, standard or custom account.  Custom will be an order of magnitude more complex.  When I have implemented Stripe and Stripe Connect for clients, I found Stripe Connect to be about as simple to implement as Stripe, however you have the added complexity of accepting payments for clients with Stripe Connect.  Plan on it taking about the about 1.5x to 2x the amount of time to implement Stripe Connect as it did to implement Stripe.

Comment: Most of the additional complexity in implementing Stripe Connect is not in the Stripe Connect API itself, but in modifying your app to handle payments for clients.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. We were planning to use the standard account. Essentially, our clients will set up on our platform to sell their products, then each time they sell a product 95% will go to their Stripe account and a small percentage will automatically be sent to our Stripe account. 

Does this mean we will have to start coding our payment system from scratch? I.e. do we have to get rid of our current code before implementing Stripe Connect? Or can it simply be 'added on' to what we already have?

Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: I cannot give a definitive answer without seeing your current code.  Some of  your code will likely be able to be reused.   However, implementing "our clients will set up on our platform to sell their products" will likely be new code unless you already have that done.  You will also need to modify your checkout process to use Stripe Connect instead of Stripe which will also be new code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!